# Removing selected files from FlaskWTF MultipleFileField

Tags: python, flask

The flask wtforms `MultipleFileField` works properly, but I was wondering if there was a way so that the user could remove certain files after choosing which ones they want to upload. Right now, after choosing what files you want to upload there is no way to remove them from the selection.

For example, if the user uploads `a.pdf` and `b.pdf` and the proceeds to exit out of the file selection and clicks upload again, the files from earlier will be removed.